# fetch api .then of calling code is executed first than the service .then which results to undefined data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have this function in my service

```
function getBreeds() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "GET"
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}breeds`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
    response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text)
        if (!response.ok) {
            const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText
            return Promise.reject(error)
        }
        return data
    })
}
```

and it was called in my vuex store

```
getBreeds({ commit }) {
    commit("getRequest")

    catService.getBreeds()
        .then(
            breeds => { 
                commit("getBreedsSuccess", breeds)  // this line of code executed first even the api is not yet finish
                console.log(breeds)
            },
            error => commit("getFailure", error)
        )
}
```

What happens is the .then in my vuex store is called first than the .then in my service which result to the breeds value became undefined. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `handleResponse` isn't returning anything, so the `getBreeds` function returns a Promise which resolves *as soon as you've received the headers* (a microtask after the `fetch` resolves), but before the response has been parsed.

Whenever you have a Promise, you should almost always either `await` or `return` it, except at the initiator, to make sure things are chained together properly. Change

```
response.text().then(text => {
```

to

```
return response.text().then(text => {
```

This will return the `.text()` Promise up to the caller, to `getBreeds` and to the caller of `getBreeds`.

(you should also probably put a `.catch` onto the end of the `catService.getBreeds` call, if it doesn't have one)